# Reading XML file leaving possible new lines

Tags: python, xml, csv, python-3.x, elementtree

I am using ElementTree to read an .xml file and save the output to a .csv file. I loop over all of the lines in the xml file and save the name and text pairs in a list.

```
savedParameters = []

tree = ET.parse(work_dir + input_name)
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    savedParameters.append({'parameterName' : child.tag, 'Value' : child.text})
    for gchild in child:
        savedParameters.append({'parameterName' : gchild.tag, 'Value' : gchild.text})
        for ggchild in gchild:
        .
        .
        .
```

I then loop over the savedParameters and write them to a csv file. This all works fine apart from in one situation, take the example from the xml below.

```
<VehicleId>123456789</VehicleId>
-<VRMs>
    <ForAppointment>X111XXX</ForAppointment>
    <Alternate>X111XXX</Alternate>
</VRMs>
<Vin>123456</Vin>
```

In this case everything will be stored as expected apart from the  field. This field should be empty however when I access child.text() it stores a blank string with a new line i.e all of the spaces between `-<VRMs>` and `</VRMs>`. Therefore when I write out to the csv it writes out the new line.

I have tried `replace(" ", "")` and `replace("\n","")` but neither solve my problem. Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: @ScottHunter, no, the code isn't the problem. I explained that child.text extracted all of the text including a 'new line' and that I was struggling removing it. I wanted to know if there is a different way to read the text or some way to manipulate the string.

Comment: Check this : https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html . does your XML file looks like ? Same pattern ?

Comment: @SDilmac, yes, the function .text would extract the value 1 from <rank>1</rank>. It is only when rank (in this example) has no text but does have some children that the .text is returning the string with an apparent new line.

Comment: What does the string look like for the `VRM`  tag , can you do `print(repr(child.text))` for that tag and let us know?

Comment: Would saving the text using `child.text.strip()` not work?

Comment: @AnandSKumar sure, `print(repr(child.text))`  returns '\n ', I had suspected this previously, however, I didn't know about repr to check it! Originally I had if '\n' in child.attrib: continue. This didn't seem to work.

Comment: @AnandSKumar, 'child.text.strip()'  seems to work. I had tried this previously and it through an error. Turns out that was something else. Thank you for the help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to strip out the newlines (from start and end of a string) using `str.strip()` (without giving any arguments) .

Example -

```
>>> s = "\n    \n asd \n    \n \n \n\n    "
>>> s.strip()
'asd'
>>> s = "\n    \n \n    \n \n \n\n    "
>>> s.strip()
''
```

As seen above, `str.strip()` would return empty string, if the string only contains whitespaces, which seems to be the case for your `child.text` . So you should be able to do - `child.text.strip()` before you try to store it in the dictionary. Example -

```
for child in root:
    savedParameters.append({'parameterName' : child.tag, 'Value' : child.text.strip()})
    for gchild in child:
        savedParameters.append({'parameterName' : gchild.tag, 'Value' : gchild.text.strip()})
        for ggchild in gchild:
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. One note for anyone else who is having a similar problem strip() will not work if .text returns a value of None. To get around this I simply used if `child.text is not None:`